# CSS: floated elements give zero height on the containing element

Tags: css-float, css

I am confused by the fact that applying `float` to `li` elements seems to mean that the containing `ul` element has no height. You can see the problem demonstrated [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CuCdr/).

Basically, I would like to create a `ul` with an arbitrary number of `li` elements. I would like each `li` element to have a width of 20%, so I end up with five `li` elements per line.

I would also like the `ul` element to have some height, so I can apply a bottom border.

If I use this class on the `li`s:

```
.result1 { 
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

then the `ul` has a height of 0. I've seen posts recommending `display: inline-block`, but if I use this instead:

```
.result2 { 
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

then the `ul` has height, but there is whitespace between the `li`s so they break over two lines.

This must be something in the CSS spec that I'm failing to understand. How can I get five elements per line, with height on the containing element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent `<ul class="results">`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lotus/CuCdr/2/)

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Would love to know a good guide for bootstrapping this kind of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Floated elements cause the parent to collapse, you need to clear the parent element.

```
.results:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CuCdr/1/